looking for resource to create my evm compatible chain with native currency
I am looking for a quick and existing solution to fork and create my own EVM-compatible chain with a native currency

Best template to start an EVM parachain.

https://github.com/paritytech/frontier-parachain-template

Best template to start an EVM solochain.

https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/master/template/runtime/src/lib.rs


first of all thanks a lot for your answer , I will need little bit more help !                                    1) does this have native currency feature ( if so how would add my currency )                       2)what basic minimum changes I need to do this template to start

Each runtime includes this code. Configure the native currency here: https://github.com/paritytech/frontier-parachain-template/blob/ac10a6a534ea3a6e8f3a433f6ec1e08a7c8b76db/runtime/src/lib.rs#L395.

These templates can be run without any modifications. However, to adapt them for your own business logic, you will need to figure that out yourself. Your second question is too unclear.

https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/master/template/runtime/src/lib.rs I tried this one, but it returned error after I launched the node template and submitted a basic transfer transaction between predefined accounts. Don't know why...
